# How to Remove/Delete a custom web part from SP2010

Tags: web-part

how to i remove/delete web-part from SP 2010

i tried the below command and it does says `operation complted successfully` but it still shows up in the custom web part bucket when adding webparts...

```
stsadm.exe -o deletesolution -name SyndicationWebPart.wsp -override
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please **retract** the solution, **delete** just removes the wsp from solution store

stsadm -o retractsolution -name `*wspfile file name*` -url ***`site url`*** -immediate

Comment: it says: `visualwebpart1.wsp does not exist in the solution store` but i can see it when i edit the page and click on insert web part

Comment: then add the solution back using stsadm -o addsolution -> then retract -> and delete

Comment: Deleting web parts that are referenced is a sure fire way to failed upgrades including patches and service packs.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you also need to remove the Web part from the site collection Web part gallery.